# Missing 25% of my btc after a resync...

Tags: balance, accounting, funds

I've got a wallet with bitcoin in it that I've had since 2011 or earlier. I was just claiming XLM using my receive addresses and the total XLM I received is about 75% of what I should have.

I checked every receive address on blockchain.info and the total btc is about 75% of what I have.

I'm not sure what to do from here.

edit: For the past few years I've had x bitcoin... the blockchain is rebuilding on my wallet right now and I'm really worried somehow I now have 25% fewer btc... wtf. I have a year and a half left to catch up on but a major receipt of btc was two years ago. I see that in my wallet but nothing else.... still 25% missing..

Answer (score 1):

If you are having a hard time syncing (maybe poor internet connection?) , try getting all your private keys using the API command "dumpwallet" and then importing them into the Electrum wallet ( there will be an option to import private keys when starting a new wallet, and import private keys into an existing wallet). Electrum, available at https://www.electrum.org, will sync almost immediately since its an SPV client and you can check your balance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use block explorers to figure out your wallet's balance. They don't know all of the addresses in your wallet so they can't tell you how much Bitcoin you actually have. What is happening here is that you have change which has gone to change addresses. Bitcoin Core will not normally show you your change addresses as you don't need to know about those and keep track of them yourself. So the "missing 25%" is likely associated with your change addresses.

Comment: God I hope so. I've got 1 year and 22 weeks left and I'm still waiting for about 25% of my btc to show up in my wallet.

Is it somehow possible to find these change addresses? I'm not actually sure what they are.

Comment: Not being synced will change the answer to your question. It is not clear in your question that you are not fully synced yet. If you are not synced, then the problem may not be with change addresses. Also, if you had restored from a backup, then there may be other issues. Can you please update your question with that information? You should wait for Core to finish syncing first and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: I was synced when I tried going through my receive addresses to claim the XLM.

A day later bitcoinqt had to resync and it's been taking days. I'm at 1 year 15 weeks right now.

Comment: Still 1 year and 3 weeks to go.

If I had, say, 4btc before but now I only have 3... after it rebuilds I should still have 4, right? I've had the amount for years.

Comment: 28 weeks left at this point... still 25% missing. Is it possible this rebuild is just screwed up and I should try again? I don't understand how else this could happen.

Comment: Somewhere between 28 weeks and 12 weeks the other 25% showed up. I don't understand the logic though. I thought btc would show up in the wallet in chronological order.

Comment: Perhaps there were transactions that you made that you forgot about.

Comment: Only one on the ledger was in May and I sent btc, I've not received since August 2016.

Comment: @Pandemic When you send BTC it uses the full balance of a utxo (or multiple utxo's) to fund the transaction. Any balance left over is sent back to you on a new receiving address. This is called change and perfectly explains what you have described.